# Application crashes on setting two onclick listener

Tags: android

I have placed the following code in the main activity in the onCreate method

```
public class MyTest extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 //... some other code here to init the layout
    Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

And have placed the following code outside the class MyTest

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            break;
    }
}
```

When running the application it crashes. Please can someone help me

Comment: "outside the class MyTest"? Don't you mean "inside"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you forgot `setContentView(R.layout.<main_xml>);`  in `onCreate()` of Activity before defining `Buttons`.

Something like,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.<main_xml>); // This line is necessary
 .
 .
 .
```

Update:

Also You have to put

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            break;
    }
}
```

at outside of `onCreate()` method as part of your `MyTest Activity Class`. Not the outside of `MyTest Activity Class`.

Comment: This is assuming the OP isn't including the `setContentView(R.layout.<main_xml>)` in the "//... some other code here to init the layout"

Comment: @Asok - Yeah you are right. Then OP needs to include stacktrace also but as you see the subject of Question then this is the only thing..

Comment: @Asok - If Buttons are **null** then only OP can't set the `onClickListener()` .SO assuming is either he forgot the `setContentView()` or the ids of buttons is not defined in the layout xml files.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had missed the setContentView

Comment: @user370305 Yeah my initial guess was missing, or misspelled id's since the "//... some other code" was shown and the `setContentView()` is auto generated when creating a new Android Application Project in Eclipse, but good catch :).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyTest extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main_xml);
    Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2); 

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
           {

                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                           Toast.makeText(myactivity.this, "The button=1 was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
           });
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
           {

                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                           Toast.makeText(myactivity.this, "The button=2 was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
           });
 }
}
```

Comment: **Bulky Code**. OP has a nice way to implement **onClickListener for Buttons**. He just missed `setContentView()` method..